# How can I store a `regex::Match` object in a struct without lifetime parameter?

Tags: rust

I'm developing on the re module in rustpython using the `regex` crate. I want to store the `Match` object in a struct without lifetimes. Is there a way to do this?

So far, I simply copied the `start` and `end` values of the match object into seperate fields, but this feels odd and wrong. There should be a way to store the `Match` object itself. (Corresponding code lives here: https://github.com/RustPython/RustPython/blob/master/vm/src/stdlib/re.rs#L78)

```rust
struct PyMatch {
    start: usize,
    end: usize,
}
```

What I would like to do is this:

```rust
struct PyMatch {
    text: &'t str,  // the original string
    m: Match<'t>,   // the match on the string
}
```

But this requires me to add the lifetime parameter `'t` to the struct `PyMatch`, which I do not want, or know how to do. Would the BoxRef crate help me here? Do I need a RefCell?

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/?search=regex, I like link to the crates you are using, I also like [mcve]

Comment: I think you can do `struct PyMatch<'t> {m: Match<'t> }`

Comment: By storing such a `Match`, you risk running into problems where the thing it matched goes out of scope. The compiler is preventing you from making a potential mistake here.

Comment: I edited the question to reflect this fact about the matched text going out of scope. Its fine to store this too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't remove the lifetime of the `Match` object, because it is defined like so:

```rust
struct Match<'t> {
    text: &'t str,
    start: usize,
    end: usize,
}
```

In other words, the `Match` object contains a reference to the text that was searched.

You didn't provide a lot of context on what exactly you're trying to do, but the straight-forward way to remove the lifetime is to define your `PyMatch` type like so:

```rust
struct PyMatch {
    text: String,
    start: usize,
    end: usize,
}
```

And then create it by copying either the entire haystack, or by copying only the part of the haystack that matched, which is likely small.

Depending on your context, if the haystack you give to the regex match function is reference counted, then you could instead define your `PyMatch` type like so:

```rust
struct PyMatch {
    // Generated from the original haystack.
    text: Rc<String>,
    start: usize,
    end: usize,
}
```

... and then that would avoid any copying in favor of just incrementing the reference count.